# SSRS Report showing blank values but on export it is showing actual values

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sqlreportingservice, reporting-services-2016

I have an report, which was working fine on my old laptope but when i use the same in my new laptop is showing blank in place of data values like image below:-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBuat.jpg)

But when i use same report after publishing on report server or i export it to excel. It shows actual values image given below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwmUa.jpg)

What may be the reason. Please help, I checked everything like server connection, font colour, data in sql is coming fine with same query, even data is correct when we execute the query in query designer of SSRS.

Pls help, thanks in advance.

1. I tried checking connection.
2. Query execution in SSRS.
3. Font & Background color properties.

Comment: Have you checked the tablix cells to see if they've been dimensioned too low or too narrow? I don't think the Excel export cares about such things.

Comment: I had clicked on allow height to increase and decrease both

Comment: Does it ever render correctly? Is it OK in Visual Studio / Report Builder? Is it OK when viewed from the server on your laptop. Have you tried another browser? Have you tried on another PC?

Comment: It is working fine on any browser. Problem is only with preview in visual studio 2015

Comment: Have you tried deleting the `.rdl.data` file (it will be next to the actual report `.rdl` file in the solution/project folder) or hit the green refresh button on the toolbar (next to the print icon). Sometimes the report uses and old cached copy of the data , either of the 2 options above will force the data to be refreshed, none of these actions will do any harm.

Comment: Yes, i did press the green refresh button 
 several times but still preview do bot show value but when exporting to excel,  values available in it.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to some screen setting issue I changed the scale from 150% to 100% and took control of my laptop from my old laptop through any desk now it is working fine for the last two days. I don't know what it did but seems like my issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same issue with a report that had previously had no issues but suddenly a cell was blank on the portal page but populated on the exports (excel, pdf, etc.).

In order to resolve the issue I had to change the `CanGrow` setting for the cell from the previously assigned `False` back to the default `True` (even though it was previously working fine with the False setting...).

This cell also had an expression defined to assign the Color property and I found that replacing that expression with a simple color assignment *also* fixed the issue but since this was needed I went with the CanGrow change.